# c# winforms, focus on form until form.Close()

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have winform app that have main form and logging form. When logging form is shown I want it to have focus until it will be closed. I tried:

```
loggingForm = new LoggingForm();
loggingForm.FormClosing += loggingForm_FormClosing;
loggingForm.bOK.Click += bOK_Click;

loggingForm.Show();
loggingForm.Activate();
loggingForm.Focus();
loggingForm.TopMost = true;
loggingForm.TopMost = false;

void loggingForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (isValidPass)
        e.Cancel = false;
    else
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Did you try showDialog?

Comment: Perfect! How can I set this answer as best one?

Comment: Posted bellow my answer.

Comment: Reading the documentation or even just looking at IntelliSense suggestions, this should have been trivial...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
loggingForm.ShowDialog();
```